# Aiohttp adding values to string in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, aiohttp

I am trying to add the user's response into the URL. My code is

```
async def dungeondata():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)) as session:
        async with session.get('https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/dungeons/{}/{}'.format(name, cutename)) as resp:
            return await resp.json()

@bot.command(name='dungeon', aliases=['dungeons'])
async def dungeon(ctx, name, cutename):
    JSONData = await dungeondata(name, cutename)
```

When the user does ?dungeons  , I am trying to add the  and  to the URL so the url becomes https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/dungeons/name/cutename. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `name` and `cutename` as arguments in `dungeon` function.

```py
async def dungeon(name, cutename):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)) as session:
        async with session.get('https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/dungeons/{}/{}'.format(name, cutename)) as resp:
            return await resp.json()
```

Comment: That does not work. I get the error raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: dungeon() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cutename'

Comment: that works, you need to pass in name and cutename when you send the command in discord

Comment: I did e?dungeon enormouz pineapple, but it did not work. Where name is enormouz and cutename is pineapple

Comment: yeah rename the dungeon function to something else as its conflicting with the command name

Comment: I have renamed it to async def dungeondata(name, cutename): but it still does not work and i get the same error. I have edited my question so it includes the changes.

Comment: Nevermind. 
I fixed the problem by adding more to the code.